# SpringBoot, SSL, https://localhost:8099/. Так и должно быть? Смотреть скриншот:)

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

application.properties

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.enabled=true
```

ServerConfig

```
@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(getHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector getHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8019);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8099);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

Всем доброго времени суток! Сегодня я решил разобраться с https для своего web-приложения, и вроде получилось. Приложение стартует на https, но терзают сомнения... В адресной строке так и должно быть "Не защищено"

Или все таки должен быть замочек? И если так, то что я мог упустить?

С этой темой я никак не знаком, и можно сказать познакомился буквально за половину дня.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где Вы взяли сертификат?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то сертификат самоподписанный. Исходя из этой статьи https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/

Comment: тогда нажмите на треугольник и почитайте, что там пишет. Если там будет написано "самоподписанный сертификат", то все ок

Comment: К сожалению этого там нет